# import external db into app and use it in android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, import

Im new to android development. Now im trying to use sqlite db.
I created a database sqlite file using sqlite manager.
I imported it to the project by /data/data/packagename/dbname, it works fine in emulator , but if I took release in device the app crashes,I didnt know what happens and why it happens. Any Suggestions for it?

Comment: Post the code showing how you transfer it from Assets to the data directory, as well as the logcat showing the error.

Comment: can you give the crash report

Comment: I had the database file  in Assets folder. I didnt know how to use it or transfer it to the data directory. but it works well with emulator. Is there any tutorial for transfering the db to datadirectory and access it. Pls, remember I had already created the db file and I have to use that only, not the new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a External DB in that manner. When you import it into your project it doesn't mean it is available in all devices from there after(Assuming you used DDMS for this). It means that DB is available to that particular emulator only. Follow the below link to find out how to add a External DB to your Application..

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 3):

```
private void StoreDatabase() {
     File DbFile=new File("data/data/packagename/DBName.sqlite");
     if(DbFile.exists())
     {
         System.out.println("file already exist ,No need to Create");
     }
     else
     {
         try 
         {
             DbFile.createNewFile();
             System.out.println("File Created successfully");
             InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("DBName.sqlite");
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DbFile);
             byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length=0;
                while ((length = is.read(buffer))>0)
                {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
             System.out.println("File succesfully placed on sdcard");
                //Close the streams
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                is.close();
         }
         catch (IOException e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
   }    
    }
```

Comment: i had a db in assets folder.but how to implement that db in my application.please any one solve my problem

Comment: how to use the external db ple help me

Comment: This code is for the same just replace packagename and DBName.sqlite with your file.

Comment: @ Krishnakant Dalal the above code works fine in emulator but not in device. what may be the reason for it

Answer (score 2):

View this link, this will be very helpful if you are using your own database in Android.

> http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

in this tutorial you have to put your database in assets folder of your project and the database will automatically transferred to database folder of you device.

Comment: this tutorial is fine but it crashed app when trying to access tables first time

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper for a helper lib to take care of this.

(I haven't used this library personally but I came across it yesterday while searching for something else. It appears to do what you need, though).